# pandas dataframe sample method causing different accuracy results after applying MultinomialNB

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')), 
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True, sublinear_tf=True)),
    ('chi2', SelectPercentile(chi2, percentile=10)),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB(alpha=0.0))])

# import data
col_names = ['user_id', 'tweet_id', 'tweet_text', 'location_code']

# this line results in approx 53% accuracy
df = pd.read_csv('data\\train-tweets.txt',delimiter='\t',names=col_names).sample(frac=0.95)

# this line results in approx 41% accuracy
df = pd.read_csv('data\\train-tweets.txt',delimiter='\t',names=col_names)

clf1 = pipeline.fit(df['tweet_text'].values, df['location_code'].values)
print 'training set:', df.shape[0], 'features:', len([val 
    for val in clf1.named_steps['chi2'].get_support() if val == True])
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, df['tweet_text'].values, 
    df['location_code'].values, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
print 'Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)' % (scores.mean(), scores.std()*2)
```

when I take a df sample I get this:

```
> training set: 203529 features: 21440
> Accuracy: 0.53 (+/- 0.00)
```

when I don't take a sample I get this:

```
> training set: 214241 features: 22205
> Accuracy: 0.42 (+/- 0.05)
```

When I take a 95% sample of the df I get an accuracy score of about 53% but when I don't sample the df I get an accuracy of about 41%. Anyone know why?